# Sentencia avanzada de SQL BILLETERA VIRTUAL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

me ocupa hacer una sentencia SQL que me permita en la misma consulta ejecutar una operacion entre 2 campos para ir mostrando el estado de cuenta de dicha billetera, procedo a describir lo que quiero hacer:

```
id id_usuario monto historial
1  22         100   100
2  22         -20    80
3  22         -10    70
```

En mi estructura SQL solo tengo el campo `monto` he buscado como dar una instrucción a la linea de codigo SQL pero no he tenido exito, solo he probado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT id, id_usuario, monto, monto as historial 
FROM `billetera` WHERE id_usuario = 22 ORDER BY `id`  DESC
```

pero logicamente solo logro tener la columna monto repetida, no se como seria la logica para que SQL haga una operacion de un dato sumandole o restando segun sea el signo del numero de la siguiente linea.

La id están ordenadas por orden cronologico es decir la primera registrada normalmente es saldo positivo y las siguientes son saldos negativos que van restándose del primer monto, hasta que vuelven a recargar que aparece otro dato positivo.

Comment: Has etiquetado MySQL y SQL Server... ¿Cuál de las dos es la correcta? Por favor, borra la que no sea correcta, porque la respuesta puede variar en función de un sistema u otro. Gracias

Comment: Los `\`` sugieren asumir MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las funciones de ventana, siempre y cuando dispongas de [mysql 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) o superior.

```
SELECT ID
    , ID_USUARIO
    , MONTO
    , SUM(MONTO) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS HISTORIAL
FROM billetera  
WHERE id_usuario = 22;
```

Si la query retornase varios id_usuario, y el historical, fuera para cada uno de ellos tendrás que establecer el id_usuario como punto de partición.

[Sumas acumuladas mySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664436/cumulative-sum-over-a-set-of-rows-in-mysql)

[image: solucion]